# Why does `a` in `a :: nil` represent a list of length 1?

Tags: list, pattern-matching, sml, ml

In  Ullman's SML book:

> Note that the way we express "list of length 1" as a pattern is to put
>   square brackets around a single identifier, like `[a]`.
>   Such a pattern can only match a list with a single element, and variable a
>   acquires that element as its value.
>
> Another way to express "list of length 1" is with the pattern `a :: nil`.
>   Again, `a` acquires the lone element as its value.

In `a :: nil`, does `a` represents the head element of a list? Why does it represent a list of length 1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is the head of the list and `nil` is the tail. `nil` is a list of length zero so `a :: nil` has length 1.